# Using combinations in Python

Tags: python

I'm using Python's argparse to get user input to select data from a test management system which match their selected status, a specific group, a specific config or a mixture of all three.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain about how to implement the mixture of all three selection. For example, if a user wants to retrieve the tests in a specific group with a specific status, the code would be

```
if ( ((args.plan_section != None) and (test_data['name'] == args.plan_section))
and ((args.test_status != None) and (test_data['test_status'] == args.test_status)) ):
    # call the test management system api
```

Though coding it like this would mean writing if/then blocks for each possible combination that a user could choose. This doesn't seem sensible - what happens when I need to add another argument (specific platform) at some point in the future?

Can somebody give a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Simplifying this depends a lot on how you call the test management api.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check against the `None`. You can compare directly:

```
if test_data['name'] == args.plan_section and \
    test_data['test_status'] == args.test_status:
```

However that will quickly become cumbersome as well. How about trying to make sure that the keys in the `test_data`-dictionary match the `argparse` options? For instance `test_data['name']` would have to be `test_data['plan_section']` (because you're comparing the `name` to `plan_section`).

You could then compare the values by first turning the `args` namespace-object to a dictionary by calling `args = vars(args)`.

Here's an example how you could compare the values in the two dictionaries:

```
>>> args = {'foo': 1, 'bar': False}
>>> test_name = {'foo': 0, 'bar': False}
>>> for k, v in args.iteritems():
...     if test_name[k] != v:
...         print "key %s does not match. args: %s, test_name: %s" % (k, v, test_name[k])

Key foo does not match. args: 1, test_name: 0
```

Or if you are only interested in the matching items and you base your api calls on those items, you can grab them from the dictionary:

```
>>> result = {k: v for k, v in args.iteritems() if test_name[k] == v}
>>> result
{'bar': False}
```

Answer (score 0):

As msvalkon said, you can remove the check against `None`. As I understand the rest of your question, you're trying to perform an action for each valid argument in `args`. What's wrong with simply writing:

```
if test_data['name'] == args.plan_section:
    # call the API to handle your first case

if test_data['test_status'] == args.test_status:
    # call the API to handle your second case
```

If any of the tests fail, Python will fall through and continue handling the remaining cases. There's no need to ensure the conditions are mutually exclusive.

If you only want to make a single API call that looks different depending on the combination of arguments passed, then the answer depends on how the API call is structured. If you wanted simply to pass the arguments from `argparse` as the arguments to the API function, you might be able to use `api_call(*args)` or similar. See the **[Python documentation on unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)** (and dictionaries).